# Possible to spit out Directed Acyclic Graph from Scons?

Tags: scons, directed-acyclic-graphs

Is there a way to get [scons](http://www.scons.org/) to output the directed acyclic graph that it internally generates?  In a graphviz format perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. You can get it to spit out the dependency tree in various detail in an ASCII-art type way, see the `--tree=xxx` option described on the [man page](http://scons.org/doc/1.2.0/HTML/scons-man.html).

Answer (score 2):

There is a python script to visualize scons dependencies with [graphviz](http://www.thomasstover.com/sconsandgraphviz/sconsandgraphviz.html).